# SSH.NET Массовая проверка ssh?

Tags: c#, ssh

Есть метод проверки `ssh` на работоспособность. В однопотоке все работает отлично. Когда я через Parallel.For начинаю использовать этот метод, он подозрительным образом некорректно срабатывает. Рабочие может определить как не рабочие и т.д.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"));
Parallel.For(0, list.Count, i =>
{
    var ip = list[i].Split(';')[0];
    var login = list[i].Split(';')[1];
    var pass = list[i].Split(';')[2];
    using (var client = new SshClient(ip, login, pass))
    {
        client.Connect();

        var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 10000, "remote.net", 80);
        client.AddForwardedPort(port);


        port.Start();
        port.Stop();
        client.Disconnect();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Задавайте для каждого потока свой локальный порт форвардинга.

```
//using System.Threading;

var list = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");

Parallel.ForEach(list,
    () => Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,    
    (i, loopState, threadId) =>    
    {
        var cells = i.Split(';');
        var ip = cells[0];
        var login = cells[1];
        var pass = cells[2];

        using (var client = new SshClient(ip, login, pass))
        {
            client.Connect();

            var port = new ForwardedPortLocal("localhost", 10000 + threadId, "remote.net", 80);
            client.AddForwardedPort(port);

            port.Start();
            port.Stop();

            client.Disconnect();
        }
        return threadId;
    },
    (threadId) => {}
);
```

Comment: http://s020.radikal.ru/i720/1510/1b/341414592b9a.png

Comment: Исправил опечатку.

Comment: Павел, еще небольшой вопрос. Как пихнуть кол-во потоков? MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Comment: Нужно экземпляр класса ParallelOptions добавить после параметра list: Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 }, ...

Comment: http://i5.imageban.ru/out/2015/10/04/37fc0a5150671c2b5f8c00ddf82a48fe.jpg Все равно работает в три потока(у меня трехядерный комп)

Answer (score -2):

Можно попробовать какие-нибудь другие средства вместо TPL. Например, оформить проверку ssh в виде метода CheckSshAsync, возвращающего `Task` или `Task<TResult>` и потом запустить задачи по списку:

```
var tasks = list.Select(listItem => CheckSshAsync(listItem));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// или var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
// если CheckSshAsync возвращает значения
```

И сравнить результаты.

Comment: Граждане минусующие, потрудитесь писать комментарии.

Comment: Скорее всего минусанули из-за того, что в данном случае никакой разницы, как именно запускается поток, нет